# Is there a function in Emacs to search the filesystem for a file by its name?

Tags: emacs

I want to open a file that is somewhere deep in my project tree.  I know the name of the file, however I don't want to go searching the tree for it.  I would like a way to enter just the file name, and have emacs search for me.  I should also be able to enter the base directory I want to start the search from, and emacs should remember that for future searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the equivalent of Textmate's `Command-T` functionality. The closest I have found for emacs is [`find-file-in-project`](https://github.com/eschulte/rinari/blob/0c3db2ffbdb1f7002c63c510b99d54ad97635776/find-file-in-project.el). It can be bound to `C-t` or a similar key for convenience: `(global-set-key "\C-t" 'ido-find-file-in-tag-files)`

Comment: This looks very promising...I was thinking Rubymine, but Textmate has it too.

Answer (score 3):

`M-x find-name-dired` is the built-in solution for this. The default directory changes according to the current buffer, but the minibuffer history contains the previous selections.

Answer (score 2):

I happen to like the `ifind.el` package which can be downloaded from the [emacswiki here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ifind.el).

Answer (score 1):

In **Icicles** you can find files by matching not just the relative file name but any parts of the path.  You can use substring, regexp, and fuzzy matching.  You can AND together multiple search patterns (progressive completion).  See multi-command `icicle-locate-file`.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input